# How to split textfile and randomly print contents [Python]

Tags: python

I have a textfile which contains:

## `text.txt`

```
achievement , a thing done successfully with effort, skill, or courage.
skill , the ability to do something well; expertise
jump , push oneself off a surface and into the air by using the muscles in one's legs and feet.
```

How can i print the sentences after the comma. Which are definitions to the word before the comma. And randomly print them with the random function. But just print one definition. Please help. thanks.

Comment: Please try at least something…

Comment: Got nothing. Stuck and need guidance. Im new.

Comment: Maybe start with [String Methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)?

Comment: @AlexLusby: Even if you are new. These are very basics of Python. I've answered you question, but at least try next time some code.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like that?

```
from random import randint

infilename = "test.txt"
allLinesList = []
with open(infilename, "r") as infile:
    allLinesList = infile.readlines()

allWords = []
definitionDic = {}

for line in allLinesList:
    splitted = line.split(",", 1)
    allWords.append(splitted[0].strip())
    definitionDic[splitted[0].strip()] = splitted[1].strip()

print "A random definition is printed:"
index = randint(0, len(allWords)-1)
print "Word: " + allWords[index] + " / Definition: " + definitionDic[allWords[index]]
```

In your question you already answered half of your question. How to split.
Just 2 basics needed. Read in a text-file and split some strings.